# Mysql schedule event in cpanel cronjob

Tags: mysql, linux, cron, cpanel

I'm using a shared webhosting and there's no option to enable the MySQL event scheduler in PhpMyAdmin. The support told me to use the cpanel cron job section instead, but it requires a linux command and I have found nothing of help for this issue.

How can I make the cpanel cron job execute this mysql command every hour?

```
UPDATE `users` SET online = `0`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need shell or php script with mysql command, smth like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/mysql -h "server-name" -u "mysql_user" "-pSECRET" -e "UPDATE `users` SET online = `0`" database_name
```

Detailed CPanel cron job setup can be found [here](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs).